# VS Code uses diffrence C++ version when "Run Code" and "Run C/C++ FIle" I want both items uses c++ 17

Tags: visual-studio-code, c++17, g++, vscode-tasks

[image: drop down list for compiling and running code in VS Code]

As you can see, When I hit "Run code", VS Code compiles the C++ file and runs it immediately in the terminal. All of this is good with one problem: it uses C++ 98.

But when I hit "Run C/C++ Code" it compiles fine with C++ 17 features. but I need an extra step to run the outputted file. I need one click to compile (with C++ features) and run the file.

I want to hit "Run Code" and it compiles the code in C++ 17, and runs the code.

Note: this is my `tasks.json` configuration

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: VS Code itself has no C/C++ support, so the menu items you saw come from the extensions you installed, and to resolve the issues you need to master each of those extensions (which you mentioned little about in the question right now).

Comment: don't use that top-right triangle, it is never mentioned in the doc pages, use F5 and launch configs

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I could add to configurations

```
"&&",
"./${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
```

to be

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "&&",
                "./${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```